# How to update WordPress jQuery version?

Tags: jquery

I've tried using plugins and by manually but javascript stopped working. If someone can help me in this regard then I'll be thankful.

Comment: You shouldn't need to upgrade jQuery, just use the version that comes with WordPress for maximum compatibility. Some plugins and themes might disable and include their own version however from a CDN under the false impression this improves performance. If that is the case you will need to contact those plugins support routes to get them to fix this ( any benefit of this is eliminated by HTTP/2, and in modern browsers has no shared caching benefit, so it is not a performance penalty, not a performance gain )

Comment: Or do you mean your own javascript that uses jQuery has stopped working and you need help to make it work again?